# How to create automount 'vboxsf' for sharing folders in Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Tags: virtualbox, automount

Ubuntu 20.04.1 complains about the command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf (username)
```

with the message:

```
usermod: group 'vboxsf' does not exist
```

I suspect that the group was not created by the virtualbox-guest-additions-iso package. So this would be a manual patch.

How to create automount 'vboxsf' for sharing folders in Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Answer (score 0):

The `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` doesn't actually install any of the Virtualbox  guest kernel modules, it literally just copies an ISO file into `/usr/share/virtualbox/`.  If you want to install the guest additions you can do one of three things:

- In the guest (assuming it's Ubuntu), install the guest additions by running `apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms`
- Mount the `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` ISO (assuming it's installed via `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`) from the host into the guest as a CD-ROM and then run the CD-ROM installer inside the guest.
- Install `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` into the guest, mount the ISO, and run the installer.  This is probably the least desirable of the three options.